All multiprocessing spawns are rerunning completed code. Should only run their function
Maybe I am not understanding how multiprocessing works, but please help with below issue.
My program runs some heavy process at startup that consolidates data for the multiprocessing function.
The heavy process should only ever run once at startup, but upon the multiprocessing code kicking in, each spawn starts executing from the top of the script agin.
This means that each spawn executes the heavy process again instead instead of just accessing the consolidated data.
The actual code results in the given behavior whether compiled using pyinstaller or been run directly from the script. The example code below exhibits the same behavior:
import multiprocessing

print("I am a heavy process that should only run once. ")

listing = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]


def multiply_it(listed):
    print([x*2 for x in listed])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    for listed in listing:
        multiprocessing.Process(target=multiply_it, args=(listed,)).start()

results in this
I am a heavy process that should only run once
I am a heavy process that should only run once
[2, 4, 6, 8]
I am a heavy process that should only run once
[10, 12, 14, 16]
I am a heavy process that should only run once
[18, 20, 22, 24]

while I am expecting this
I am a heavy process that should only run once
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[10, 12, 14, 16]
[18, 20, 22, 24]

Any help will be appreciated

Your print() is before the if name==main:, so it gets re-executed as each process starts. Just move the print() inside the if.

@quamrana. Thank you,  I tried it on the example provided, and it works. Let me reconfigure my main program and I will get back to you. I am a joke if it works there as well. Not sure if you want to post it as an actual answer incase it works?

Your original question is probably a duplicate, so I'll wait an see your update before trying to close.

On Windows, python needs to reimport the module to access the code you want to run. It calls that module __mp_main__. That's why you need the if __name__ == "__main__" check. Everything at module level will execute again. In your case, the print and the initialization of listing. That's where you'll find the dups here on SO -

And as a side note, linux (and I think mac) fork the process and don't need to reimport. People running your example on those platforms won't see the bug unless they also add multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn") to change how subprocesses are created.

@quamrana. Unbelievable how much time I wasted on this. Glad I asked any and thanks for the help. Not sure if you close this as duplicate if it does already exist.

@tdelaney. Thank you for that explanation. Makes sense now that I have seen live in my code.

We should close it ... I'm being a bit lazy and haven't looked one up.

The closest I can find is this question. I'll let someone else propose this as a duplicate.

@quamrana, not a problem. Thanks again

Adding to what @tdelaney said about multiprocessing.set_start_method. There are three different start methods. Not all are available on all platforms, and the default start method is not the same on every platform. See the official API docs for details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-start-methods

import multiprocessing

def worker_function(data):
    # This function will be executed by each worker process
    print(f"Processing {data}")
    return data * data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Ensure this code runs only in the main process
    data_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker_function, data_list)
    print(results) 

Detail Example
import multiprocessing

def pull_data():
    print("Pulling data...")
    # Simulate data pulling
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def preprocess_data(data):
    print("Preprocessing data...")
    # Simulate preprocessing
    return [x * 2 for x in data]

def worker_function(data):
    print(f"Processing {data}")
    return data * data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pull_data()
    processed_data = preprocess_data(data)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker_function, processed_data)
    print(results)


Thank you for you assistance. I tried your code as well and it works as expected. Unfortunately I tried quamrana suggestion first so if he does post it as an answer, I will have to mark his as the correct one assuming this is not closed as a duplicate. Have upvoted yours in the interim
